# How to draw a pointer in Java?

Tags: java, background, jcomponent, markers

I've got JLabel as a background of my JPanel. I need to display over 400 points there in different coordinates taking from db. How can I draw so many markers automatically?

Comment: The "pointers" you have tagged is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an ArrayList of points to paint. Then you can override the paintComponent() method of the label to first paint the image (by invoking super.paintComponent()), then you iterate through the ArrayList and paint each point.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of painting objects from an ArrayList.